# Непонятно отображается display:grid, не учитывает columns gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid, width

Пытаюсь сверстать страничку, надо чтобы элементы формы были посередине. Все сделал, но забыл что в placeholder нужна иконка от FontAwesome. Сделал через :before, соответственно создав обертку, ибо к input не применяется. После этого все полшло поехало, если убираю для форм width:100%; то не растягивается на весь див, если ставлю 100%, то просто игнорирует columns gap. До создания обертки все было норм, даже ширину вручную не пришлось ставить. Скрины 1)как должно быть 2)первый вариант 3)второй вариант. Собственно что не так с кодом то? Может я в шары долблюсь и не вижу чего то. Help!!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il4NC.png  ====== 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XX5Z.png   =======

```css
/*FORM==================================*/
.form_request_a_quote {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 92.735%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.form_request_a_quote>.form {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 0.75fr;
 grid-column-gap: 12px;
}

.kostil1 {
 
}

.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_full_name_div>input,
.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_email_div>input,
.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_phone_div>input,
.form_request_a_quote>.form>button {
 border-width: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 height: 50px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 13px;
 color:#b4b4b4;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
 border-radius: 3.5px;
 
}

.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_full_name_div>input,
.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_email_div>input,
.form_request_a_quote>.form>.form1_phone_div>input {
 padding:0px 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.form_request_a_quote>.form>button {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #ffbb42;
 transition: 0.22s;
}

.form_request_a_quote>.form>button:hover {
 color:#ffbb42;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.form1_full_name_div {
 position: relative;
}

.form1_full_name_div:before {
 content: "\f183";
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 color: gray;
 font-size:13.5px;
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5px;
 top: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_request_a_quote">
    
    <form action="#" class="form">
     
     <div class="form1_full_name_div" class="kostil1"><input type="text" class="form1_full_name" class="kostil1" placeholder="Full Name"></div>
     <div class="form1_email_div" class="kostil1"><input type="email" class="form1_email" class="kostil1" placeholder="E-Mail"></div>
     <div class="form1_phone_div" class="kostil1"><input type="text" class="form1_phone" class="kostil1" placeholder="Phone"></div>
     <button class="kostil1" class="form_request_a_quote_button">
      
      request a quote

     </button>
    </form>

   </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXwZj.png

Comment: grid-gap: 0 12px:  так проверьте

Comment: то же самое :((

Comment: а если просто  .form написать ?

Comment: все равно то же. Непонятки короче. Суть в том что input вылезает за пределы div и игнорирует columns gap.Ну, как я понял, естественно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, дело было в том что почему то к этим элементам не применялось box-sizing: border-box; из-за этого пэддинг расширял инпуты. Банально, но щито поделать.

```
*, 
*before, 
*after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Прописано в самом начале, почему не применялось я до сих пор не знаю.

Comment: *:before, *:after . И это не нужно, потому как у них значение box-sizing идет inherit.

Comment: Поздновато отвечаю, но спасибо <3